# how to convert tapestry arraylist into array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arraylist, dropdown

I am working on an application that uses tapestry , jquery , ajax .

I need to get a drop down to act as  autocomplete drop down.
So i think of taking drop down option arraylist into an array and write autocomplete method to it .
below is existing code

```
          <td ><span jwcid="countryList"
                        onChange="javascript:onChangeCountry(this);" />
          </td>
```

Above tag converts into  drop down box at run time with id = countryList.

I want to get text values of countryList into an array , how can i do it ?
I tried below method , but it only gave me  first index 's text .

```
     var carray= [];
       $('#countryList :selected').each(function(i, selected){
         carray[i] = $(selected).text();
         });

     $( "#xyz" ).autocomplete({                 
                source: carray
                });
```

How can i get all text values in carray ?

What am i doing wrong  ?

Please help .

Thanks Much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the `option` like this. You can try with this code instead:

```js
var options = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#myselect option').each(function(i, selected) {
    options[i] = ($(selected).text());
  });

  console.log(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: options.push worked ! . Thanks much . is push jquery method ?

Comment: @summary - welcome. `.push()` is standard javascript function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: earlier i was writing $('#myselect option').each(function(i, selected) {
   carry[i] = $(selected).text();
  }); But it wasn't working .

Comment: even that should have worked. updated the answer with the same. You might be having issue somewhere else.

Comment: Though this Q has been answered  , just want to know can how autocomeplete can be achieved by using Suggest component of tapestry 4.1.2 .  OR is it like Suggest works only  for those  arraylist having  text values ( no values )  . in my case CountryList has country code as value and country name as text .